# Backup Outlook 2007 WITHOUT auto archive

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, archiving

The company I work for recently came up with a rule "All emails older than 3 months (90 days) will be automatically deleted." Applies to Inbox, Sent Items AND Calendar.
This was implemented without any advance notice/warning and my older emails started disappearing silently. Auto Archive is NOT disabled/greyed out. So I was under the impression that it was working but it's not. 
So, without manually saving emails, what is my best workaround this rule so I can continue to retain emails older than 90 days? I'd like to be able to save them to an archive file so they can appear in my Archive folder.
Yes, Auto Archive is designed exactly for this but, well, the powers that be in my firm decreed against it.

Thanks, 
Shashi

Comment: Because this is a corporate computer and you are attempting to circumvent corporate policy, this question should be closed. There are reasons why IT departments are directed to come up with these policies, most of them legal.

Comment: What happens if you create a local .pst file that you archive to?

Comment: Tell your management that you cannot do your job without having these older messages available.

Answer (score 1):

Create Local (Personal) Folders in Outlook 2007 and password protect it. 
https://helpdesk.umd.edu/documents/4/4992/Outlook2007LocalFolders.pdf
Always ask network admins if this is allowed in your network.